# Setting up OpenGL: Why am I getting these errors? Why is Visual Studio Freezing?

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012

So I have been programming in console C++ for a while, but I finally decided to try graphical applications using OpenGL. It took me a while to learn that GLUT and other libraries are obsolete, so I began installing and preparing GLEW and FreeGLUT. I managed to get to the point were my includes are working; however, now I'm running into this problem:

[image: Screenshot]

Visual Studio is telling me that I don't have glew32.dll when it is clearly sitting in the system32 folder. Is this not the default folder for these libraries?

In addition, every time I run my program (and hence get this error) the visual studio process continues running in the background, even after the program is closed. It refuses to be ended and it causes another problem: whenever I reenter Visual Studio I get a message saying that the default storage location is currently in use by another instance of visual studio (the one running in the background.) As a result, to continue working I have to restart my computer every time.

Does anyone have any clue what could be wrong with this and how I could get things up and running? This is my first time installing libraries, but I haven't touched random things in the system folder (at least not intentionally) and I've been careful to clean up behind myself when I've done something I shouldn't have.

Other info:

Visual Studio 2012
Latest stable releases of freeGLUT and GLEW
Windows 8.1 64bit

Comment: Judging from your screenshot you're not using vs2012 but vs2013 express version. Are you mixing up paths for vs2013 and vs2012?

Comment: Did you try to copy glew32.dll and the library of freeglut into the Debug folder of your project?

Comment: @David Maybe, I thought it odd as I did just update Visual Studio and I thought the 2012 didn't seem right. Will doublecheck.

Comment: @joschuck No I didn't, should I have? I'm not familiar with using libraries, especially external ones.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I appreciate your response, but most of your advice goes over my head. I'm not sure what you mean when you say "link against" and while I understand that there is alarm at the glew32.dll in the system folder, I did as some tutorials instructed and I am unaware what I am supposed to do with such things. A solid explanation or a link to one, would be greatly appreciated. I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: Yes, when you use the dynamic-linked version glew32.lib you have to copy glew32.dll in the folder of your executable like Andon M. Coleman suggested.

Comment: So where do I find this executable folder? Right now my project has yet to even be built. More importantly I need to fix my Visual Studio problems, as these background processes are making me have to restart every time I run the program to test it.

Comment: @DesertEagle_PWM: By default when Visual Studio runs your program (e.g. you hit F5 to debug or Ctrl+F5 to run normally) it will do so from your solution's root directory. In your case, that location would be: "C:\Users\Austin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\project3\". This is where you would need to put your DLLs. However, the **.exe** is actually located in "...\Debug". If you were to double click on your **.exe** to run the program, then that is the location you should put your DLLs - Visual Studio mixes things up a little bit by making the "working directory" different.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you, I was too busy looking in my programs folders. I found the root; is this the working directory or is that the debug (with the .exe?)

Comment: @DesertEagle_PWM: When you run it through Visual Studio, it will set the working directory to the root directory I mentioned. But if you were to open Windows Explorer and double click on the .exe file, Windows is going to set the directory the .exe file is in as the working directory. Generally, the working directory is the same as the location of the .exe (for instance, if you were to run it from cmd.exe or double click it) but software can always tell Windows to use a different working directory (which Visual Studio does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### There are a few things worth mentioning here:

1. You really should not even bother with using the **dynamic** linking version of glew (`glew32.lib`). Just link against the **static** linking library (`glew32s.lib`) and forget that the DLL version ever existed.

   - The DLL version is more trouble than it is worth, especially since it will not work with other compilers (e.g. g++) on Microsoft Windows.
2. For goodness' sake, do not install **glew32.dll** to **System32**!

   - Never, ever, put any user DLLs there. This is the primary cause of "DLL hell." What you should do is distribute them along with your application instead (e.g. in your .exe's working directory) or if the software has a run-time redistributable installation program (glew does not) ship that with it.
3. I am willing to bet good money you are running a 64-bit version of Microsoft Windows.

   - You are compiling a 32-bit application, and it will run in Microsoft Windows' 32-bit compatibility layer known as **Windows on Windows**. All 32-bit DLLs will be sourced from a separate location **SysWow64** when running in the compatibility layer.
   - This can be confusing, as you would think that **System32** means 32-bit... but for historical reasons **System32** actually contains the DLLs for the *native* version of Windows (32-bit on Win32 and 64-bit on x64).
   - Nevertheless, ***do not*** install **glew32.dll** to **SysWoW64** either :)

---

Since you mentioned in comments that you do not understand what "linking against glew32s.lib" means, I will tell you simply that this line in your header file is causing the linker to use the DLL version of glew:

```
 #pragma comment (lib, "glew32.lib")
```

This is an ugly hack for the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler that tells the linker to add this as a dependency. It is not understood by other compilers (e.g. g++), but if your software is always going to be compiled with Visual Studio you can continue to use it.

To change your software to use the **static** (non-DLL) version of glew, simply replace that line with this:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "glew32s.lib")
```

Now you do not need to distribute a DLL along with your program and this whole problem effectively disappears.

Comment: Thanks for your help, there is obviously still a lot I need to learn about correctly managing/installing/using/linking libraries. Any helpful links from anyone here on out or tips on fixing the Visual Studio issue would certainly help.